# Project Euler Problem - 1 does not return the value I expected

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I did not learn loops using `for` yet, so I solved this problem using `while` but I can't find the issue with my problem, sum should be **233168** apparently, and I am getting **234168** I simply cannot identify where I missed it.

**Question**: **If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.**

**Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.**

```java
package net.projecteuler;

public class Problem01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int n, sum;
        boolean notFinished = true;
        n = 0;
        sum = 0;
        
        
        while(notFinished) {
            if(n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0) {
                sum = (sum + n);
            }
            n = (n + 1);
            if(n > 1000) {
                notFinished = !true;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("A soma dos números é " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the problem definition?

Comment: Sure, sorry, I forgot.

https://projecteuler.net/problem=1

Comment: No, *in the text of the question*.  We want our questions to be self-contained.

Comment: There you go, sorry.

Comment: Even without the problem statement, I'm inclined to guess that you have an off-by-one error.  The difference between the expected value and the computed value is 1000, which is apparently at the endpoint of your iteration.  As the logic is structured, your code will perform an iteration with `n == 1000` before it quits, and presumably it's not supposed to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is wrong. The problem statement is (bolding for emphasis):

> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 **below 1000**.

Whereas your program also sums `1000` itself, which is divisible by `5`. If you change the condition `n > 1000` to `n >= 1000`, you'll get the correct answer.

Side note: You should really look into `for` loops. That would be a much better fit for this challenge.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will be looking into ```for``` really soon. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is wrong. The while loop runs one too many times, because you are comparing `n > 1000` instead of `n >= 1000`.

With that being said, you can also improve your loop. The boolean variable is not needed, as you can straight up check the condition in the while statement, like this - `while (n < 1000)`.

In addition, if you are going to use your boolean variable, I would probably not set it to `false` by saying `isFinished = !true`, but by doing `isFinished = false` or `isFinished = !isFinished`.

Comment: Or just `break`.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly your issue is with the `if` condition. It should be `n >= 1000`

Also you can simplify your algo like this. An alternative solution to your question.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sum(1000, 3, 5));
    }

    private static int sum(int i, int a, int b) {
        i = --i;
        int c = a * b;
        int k1 = i / a;
        int k2 = i / b;
        int k3 = i / c;

        return (k1 * (a + (k1 * a)))/2 + (k2 * (b + (k2 * b)))/2 - (k3 * (c + (k3 * c)))/2;
    }
}
```

*Note this only works if `a` and `b` are prime numbers. If `a` and `b` are not prime, then `c` should be `LCM` of `a` and `b`*

```
int c = lcm(a,b)
```